# Filter array to keep only if object value is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I let my users save their settings.

I got an array that looks like this:

```
[{"email"=>true}, {"alert"=>true}, {"push"=>false}]
```

The desired outcome for the above array is below. I want to only keep the object/value in the array if the value is true. If it is false it should not show up in the new array.

```
["email", "alert"]
```

Comment: A scenerio where an object contains multiple keys how will that be handled

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this array

```
settings = [{"email"=>true}, {"alert"=>true}, {"push"=>false}]
```

You need the following

```
settings.map { |item| item.keys.first if item.values.first == true }.compact
=> ["email", "alert"]
```

Comment: Good answer, but maybe remove the `== true` part as it is redundant. (The `.compact` part is also possibly redundant as well depending on the dataset.)

Comment: Good catch about the `== true` part but the compact is not redundant as the thing returned is `['email', 'alert', nil]` so to delete all the `nil` values we need `.compact`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{"email"=>true}, {"alert"=>true}, {"push"=>false}]
```

```
arr.filter_map do |h|
  k, v = h.flatten
  k if v
end
  #=> ["email", "alert"]
```

---

See [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten) and [Hash#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten).

---

If

```
h = {"email"=>true}
```

then

```
k, v = h.flatten
  #=> ["email", true]
k #=> "email"
v #=> true
```

Since `v #=> true` `k` is appended to the array that is returned by `filter_map`.